# Html nested element remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**HTML**

```
<li id="tree0_2_2" data-rowkey="0_2_2">
    <span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span class="ui-state-highlight">Something</span>
    </span>
</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
var removedNode = $('#tree0_2_2');
$(removedNode.find(".ui-state-highlight")).removeClass('.ui-state-highlight');
```

I tried this but it didin't worked.

How can i remove class *'ui-state-higlight'* ?

Comment: you don't need the class selector (`.`) in the `removeClass` method.

Comment: ty all for so quick reponses. silly me. i forgot to remove '.'. All the answers are correct so im chosing one of them random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably missed the closing quote and remove `.` from `removeClass`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/UpHYD/1/)**

```
var removedNode = $('#tree0_2_2');
removedNode.find(".ui-state-highlight").removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
```

removedNode is jQuery object and you do not need to pass it to `$()` again. You can reduce it to single statement.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/UpHYD/2/)**

```
$('#tree0_2_2 .ui-state-highlight').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
```

Comment: And remove . from removeClass function attribute

Comment: Thanks @Mr.TK, so nice of you. I already changed

Comment: Somebody downvoted You so I had to comment this and Upvote Your answer. It was correct in 100% but did not have the **whole answer**.

Comment: There were two problems and and I missed the second in first glance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need in `.` before the class name in `removeClass`:

```
$('#tree0_2_2').find('.ui-state-highlight').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
```

**N.B.:** You don't actually need to wrap the jQuery object in another jQuery object several times, just do it once, as displayed in the solution above.

Answer (score 1):

try this. your code is contains many syntax error

```
$('#tree0_2_2').find("span.ui-state-highlight").removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
```

your code be like this

```
var removedNode = $('#tree0_2_2');
removedNode.find(".ui-state-highlight").removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$("#tree0_2_2 .ui-state-highlight").removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
```

Or

```
$(".ui-state-highlight", "#tree0_2_2").removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
```

Comment: can you explain in what means it would extract the wrong result.? :)

Comment: @sudharsan Now it is right.

Comment: @sudharsan hence the proof.. http://jsfiddle.net/y6E5z/7/

Comment: @sudharsan :D http://jsfiddle.net/y6E5z/8/

Answer (score 1):

**HTML :**

```
<li id="tree0_2_2" data-rowkey="0_2_2">
    <span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span class="ui-state-highlight">Something</span>
    </span>
</li>
```

**JQuery :**

```
var removedNode = $('#tree0_2_2');
removedNode.find(".ui-state-highlight").removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
```

After making variable you don't need to write `$(removedNode.find())`